# Machines whose languages are their own encoding

Tags: computability, reductions, undecidability

Is the language $S = \{\langle M \rangle \mid M \text{ is a Turing Machine and } L(M) = \{\langle M \rangle\}\,\}$ decidable, recognizable and/or co-recognizable?

I tried diagonalization but can only prove that $R = \{\langle M \rangle \mid M \text{ is a Turing Machine and } \langle M \rangle \notin L(M)\}$ is not recognizable, which does not seem to help in this case...

Comment: I'd try a few attempts exploiting the s-m-n theorem and the 2nd recursion theorem to build quine-like TMs. It might lead to a useful m-reduction. (Why is this marked complexity-theory ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the recursion theorem, for any Turing machine $T$ you can construct a Turing machine $M$ such that on input $\langle M \rangle$, $M$ executes $T$ (on the empty tape), and otherwise $M$ immediately rejects. You can use this to show that $S$ is not decidable. Using the same ideas you can explore its recognizability and co-recognizability.

Comment: If I understand correctly: If S is decidable, there is a decider for $S$ denoted as $H$. To obtain a contradiction, we construct a TM $B$ such that on input $w$, $B$ ignores $w$ and obtains a description of itself $\langle B\rangle$. Then $B$ run $H$ on $\langle B\rangle$. For the output, $B$ reject if $H(\langle B\rangle)$ accept and accept if $H(\langle B\rangle)$ reject. So the output of $B$ is always in contradiction with itself?

Comment: This is one way, though you can avoid diagonalization.

Comment: Any thoughts on recognizability though? I suspect it is not recognizable but have no idea about its proof.

Comment: It's your exercise. I won't give further hints. Sometimes solving an exercise takes time. Be patient.